# SBS 2008 and Windows 2008 Standard CAL's

Tags: windows-sbs-2008, licensing, cal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

My client has bought Windows 2008 SBS Standard version. If he buys Windows 2008 Standard does he needs additional CAL's for the Standard version? I'm asking this since he bought the Standard version of SBS instead of Premium one, so by buying another version of Windows 2008 Standard he could save some costs of buying new SBS 2008 Premium. But can he use the SBS 2008 CAL's on the W2K8 STD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Microsoft there's no way to upgrade SBS 2008 Standard to Premium without buying the whole SBS Premium Edition which kinda blows up the whole purpose.

There are couple of workarounds:

1. One can buy missing Windows 2008 Standard and use SBS Standard CAL's - in other words you don't have to buy additional Windows 2008 Standard CAL's, you can use the ones from SBS, as long as the Windows is in the same domain.
2. When one decides that he needs SQL on that Windows 2008 Standard he needs to buy both SQL and missing CAL's for SQL. He can't use SBS 2008 Premium CAL's for that.

And some other things that I've learnt while speaking to Microsoft employees:
 1. If you have SBS Premium but some of your users don't use SQL they don't need SBS Premium CAL's. They can use SBS standard CAL's. So in other words you can mix Premium CAL's with Standard CAL's as long as the people assigned to standard CAL's don't use SQL.